# JWPlayer wait 5 seconds to do a action after complete video

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I need to configure the JWPlayer to wait 5 seconds (countdown) and execute the next video, I wanna show a "Loader" in the center of video like the Youtube do.
I have this code,

```html
onComplete: function() {
   if ($('input[type=checkbox][name=status]:nth(0)').attr('checked', false)) {
     $('input[type=checkbox][name=status]:nth(0)').trigger("click");
   }

   setTimeout(explode, 5000);
   function explode(){
     NextPage.next();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to trigger an event when the video completes and insert your desired behavior in the function.

```
jwplayer().on('complete', function(){

    });
```

Example code: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/search/?k=apiCalls&q=on(%27complete%27)

Comment: Nativevely, I discovered that the jw player does not have this function